# Report With UP-Down Indicator In SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

--Sales Table

```
ID  |   Sales
-------------
1   |   100
-------------
2   |   110
-------------
3   |   120
-------------
4   |   130
-------------
5   |   100
-------------
6   |   90
-------------
7   |   80
-------------
8   |   90
-------------
9   |   100
-------------
10  |   110
-------------
11  |   70
-------------
12  |   80
-------------
13  |   90
-------------
14  |   100
-------------
15  |   110
-------------
16  |   80
-------------
```

--Output table

```
FromID  |   ToID    |   SalesIndicator
-------------------------------------------------
1   |   4   |       UP
-------------------------------------------------
4   |   7   |       Down
-------------------------------------------------
7   |   10  |       UP
-------------------------------------------------
10  |   11  |       Down
-------------------------------------------------
11  |   15  |       UP
-------------------------------------------------
15  |   16  |       Down
-------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see, i have two tables. Sales table and output which i want. Output table contain three columns FromID, ToID and SalesIndicator.

Lets take the example of first row. In the sales table from ID 1 to ID 4, sales is increasing hence indicator is Up.

Lets take the example of second row. In the sales table from ID 4 to ID 7, sales is decreasing hence indicator is Down.

Please help me to write a code which will populate the output table using sales table.

Thank You,
Akash

Comment: FromId and ToID not contain same interval.It is correct data?like 7 to 10 and then 10 to 11

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky question. Loved writing query for it. I have added an answer, is not the best one, still I am happy to post this. Please check:

```
;WITH T AS (
    SELECT 
        *, ID IDA, 1 CNT, 1 UPD 
    FROM YourTable where ID=1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        b.*, 
        T.ID,
        (case when T.Sales<b.Sales then t.CNT else T.CNT+1 end),
        (case when T.Sales<b.Sales then 1 else 0 end)
    from YourTable b INNER JOIN T on b.ID=T.ID+1
)
,x as(
    select 
        *, 
        case when UPD=0 then ID-CNT else CNT end ToGroup
    From T
)
SELECT 
    MIN(IDA) FromID, 
    MAX(ID) ToID,
    CASE WHEN UPD=1 then 'Up' else 'Down' end SalesIndicator
FROM x
GROUP BY UPD, ToGroup
ORDER BY MIN(IDA)
```